# Importing a PFX Certificate Via MMC adds multiple entries instead of one

Tags: powershell, openssl, certificate, windows-server-2016, pfx

This is definitely a gross misunderstanding on how this works, but I cannot find an answer to this issue.

I've created a .pfx Cert on OSX using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycompanyhere.com.pfx -inkey comp-com.key -in comp-com.crt -certfile comp-ca.crt
```

When the exported .pfx is transferred to a Windows Server 2016 and  imported into the certificate manager it creates 3 separate entries, where i expected ***just one***

I know this is incorrect (or at least this method is doing something different) as i have previously created a .pfx within windows server using the `Export-PfxCertificate`  command after importing a cert and using that.

Id like to use the openssl method ideally via my terminal, but if thats not possible it would be great to get an explanation as to why this wont work or  what I am misunderstanding.

Thanks,

D

Comment: Why what won't work? What are the 3 entries, and what's wrong with having three entries? What was in `comp-com.crt` and `comp-ca.crt`? I'm guessing one was your certificate and the other was a two-certificate chain, and all those three are in the pfx ?

Comment: That is correct, as previously mentioned using Export-PfxCertificate it took a .crt i uploaded previously and exported it to pfx, which when imported created 1 entry.

Comment: "As previously mentioned" - what was your `Export-PfxCertificate` command? The help for that says it builds a chain by default, unless you tell it not to. So either you told it not to, or your certificate in that case somehow didn't have a chain (was it a root cert? or it didn't have the chain in the store available to put in the pfx) ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Export-PfxCertificate` you specified to create a PFX around one certificate (and its private key).  Your `openssl pkcs12` says to create a PFX with three certificates and one private key.

If you only want one thing in the PFX, don't specify the `-certfile` argument, then it's just "a certificate and its private key".

A PFX can hold any non-negative number of certificates, any non-number of private keys, and any number of a couple of other kinds of things (mostly up to the maximum data size a system is willing to read on PFX import).